# Is it possible to serialize a struct , that implements an interface, using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I am getting the error: `'Unexpected sub-type: StructId'` when calling `Serializer.Serialize(stream, Id);`
The entities are defined as follow :

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(101, typeof(ClassId))]
[ProtoInclude(102, typeof(StructId))]
public interface Id{}

[ProtoContract]
public class ClassId : Id {..}

[ProtoContract]
public struct 
StructId : Id {..}
```

I have also tried to call `Serializer.PrepareSerializer<Id>();` , but it doesn't work either.
Is it not supported or am I doing something wrong?